# I want to know how to put continuous values in wx.ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to output 1 ~ 100 output to the scroll `wx.panel` with a for statement, but only the last 100 value is output. I want to know what to do and can I accumulate values ​​in the general panel? And I want to know how to scroll automatically without using the `SetScrollbars` method.

```
import wx

class test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        main = wx.ScrolledWindow(self)
        main.SetScrollbars(10,10,10,10)

        for i in range(1,101):
            print(i)
            wx.StaticText(main, label=str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = test()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have additional questions. How do I reverse the order from 1 to 100 in order of 100 to 1?

Does wx.TextCtrl also have a reverse function? Finally, I wonder if I need to do the conversion work to output an Oracle RTF statement to wx.TextCtrl.

Oracle RTF:

```
{\ rtf1 \ ansi \ ansicpg949 \ deff0 \ deflang1033 \ deflangfe1042 {\ fonttbl {\ f0 \ fnil \ fcharset129 \ 'b1 \' bc \ 'b8 \' b2 \ 'c3 \' bc;}}
{\ Colortbl; \ red0 \ green0 \ blue0;}
\ Viewkind4 \ p1 \ pard \ cf1 \ lang1042 \ f0 \ fs20 vulva - marked improved
\ Par \ cf0 \ fs20
\ Par}
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that you want a `wx.ScrolledWindow` to achieve your aim.
Try this:

```
import wx
import time
class test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,400),
                        style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.VSCROLL)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()
        for i in range(1,101):
            self.log.AppendText(str(i)+"\n")
            self.log.ShowPosition(-1)
            self.panel.Update()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            wx.Yield()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = test()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Arguably, the sizer is not required but you may want to add in some control buttons, like `Stop` at a later date, which having the sizer will allow you to do.
The call to `Yield` allows you to see what is happening during the loop and be able to click a `Stop` button in the future.
The call to `time.sleep` is there only to slow things down and `ShowPosition` keeps the last item added in focus.